# Help in understanding "Local well-posedness for the Maxwell-Schrodinger system"

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Is there someone who knows the following paper

"Local well-posedness for the Maxwell-Schrodinger system" by M.Nakamura and T.Wada.

I'm trying to study it but I've some doubts. In particular I'm not really understanding where they use the assumption $s\geq \frac{5}{3}$.

Comment: They use the assumption $s\geq 5/3$ in the estimate (6.10). They apply the fractional Leibniz rule to the product in combination with the Sobolev embedding of $H^{s-1,2}$ to $L^q$ where they use $1-1/\tilde{r} = 1/2 +1/q$ and choose $\tilde{r} = 3/(4-2s)$. The Sobolev embedding then only works for $s\geq 5/3$.

Comment: @gsa Thank you. I stopped before that lemma and I was trying to understand it with previous computations.

Comment: @gsa May I ask you to clarify another doubt I have? Why do you think they use estimates for Klein-Gordon equations and not estimates for the wave equation?

Comment: Maybe it's possible to work with the wave equation as well. But the standard Strichartz estimates for the wave equation are stated in the homogeneous Sobolev spaces $\dot{H}^{s,p}$, which are a bit delicate. My guess is that they prefer to work with the inhomogeneous spaces $H^{s,p}$ and thus use the Strichartz estimates for Klein-Gordon.

Comment: @gsa But the wave equation has also a conservation of energy which can be used. I have to think about it, because it's not very clear to me.

Comment: @gsa Maybe one reason could be that using Strichartz estimates for Klein-Gordon they get a larger range for the values of $\sigma$ of that they would obtain using energy inequality for the wave equation.

Comment: I think MO is not the best place for such a discussion. I updated my profile so that you can find my email address.